# Disable Cache of okhttp

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

i know to disable cache of okhttp is to call `Request.cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)`. Is it possible to set the cacheControl from OkHttpClient.class? Because i have 1 client for all my request. So i want to disable cache for all the request by disabling it from the okhttpClient

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this to build Retrofit and provide cache as `null` the API will not cache anything.

```
private OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            ...
            .cache(null)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: what is mCache?

Comment: its a cache file if you want to provide cache you can define it.

Comment: is it ok if i dont use `readTimeout` , `connectTimeout`, and `writeTimeout` and only use the `cache()`?

Comment: Yes, it's a builder class you have full choice to pass any required value.

Comment: not worked in my case

Answer (score 15):

add interceptor to your client, and add cache control header in interceptor.check sample code below:

```
    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder().addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };

    OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the result of newBuilder().